# Reverse content of Queue

Tags: java, queue

I have a queue (Q) = 1,4,6,9,2,7,5 which I got by merging two queues.
I want to reverse this queue as 5,7,2,9,6,4,1 using reverse method in Java.
 This is what I have

```
 List<Integer> myQueue = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 4, 6, 9, 2, 7, 5));
```

Comment: show an attempt, no one will do this for you. How about pushing everything onto a stack and then popping the stack into a new queue?

Comment: What code have you written to solve this problem? We'll gladly answer and critique your coding questions but all we ask is that you show us what you first attempted yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java: reverse list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962766/java-reverse-list)

Comment: Please help me reopen this . I have updated the Question with the code I have. Due to this they have blocked me from asking questions in Stackoverflow. I will not post such questions again. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is quite simple.   First line creates the queue.  Second shows it to you.  Third reverses it.  Fourth prints it out showing that is was reversed.

```
    List<Integer> queue = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 4, 6, 9, 2, 7, 5));
    System.out.println(queue);
    Collections.reverse(queue);
    System.out.println(queue);
```

The output of which is:

```
    [1, 4, 6, 9, 2, 7, 5]
    [5, 7, 2, 9, 6, 4, 1]
```