# Is there a way to begin the enhanced for loop from the end in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I have two lists in Java. For one, i want to iterate from the beginning and for the other I want to start from the end. I wanted to use enhanced for loop for this, but i am unsure how to do that.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Firstly, you should try by your own. It isn't that complicated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962766/java-reverse-list

Comment: Why do you need to use the enhanced for loop? It makes the most common case really simple, but you still have the original for-loop to handle all the other, less frequent, cases.

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot use the Enhanced For-Loop to iterate from the end to the beginning of a List. Enhanced For-Loops should be used for simplicity when you wish to step through the elements in a first-to-last order. In any other cases, the "standard" For-Loop is the most optimal.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a copy of the list and reverse it:

```
List<T> listCopy = new ArrayList<T>(list);
Collections.reverse(listCopy);
for(T t : listCopy) {
    ... 
}
```

You can also use a [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) (the enhanced for loop uses an `Iterator` in the background):

> An iterator for lists that allows the programmer to traverse the list in either direction.

Comment: Performance wise not Optimal and Wise  !

Comment: Actually the answer should be that there is no way to do exactly what the OP wants. Any workaround is not optimal.

Comment: Guava Lists has a util to reverse without copy: Lists.reverse(letters)

Comment: @tkruse That's a nice option, and it uses a custom `ListIterator` as I mentioned in the answer. Anyway I think you should write the Guava solution as an answer :)

Comment: It's mentioned in both questions linked as related, this question really is a duplcate that should be closed, So I won't answer. Feel free to extend your answer though,