# Java : Joining String from List<String> in reverse order

Tags: java, string, arraylist, reverse

I have `List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");` 
I want to join all string inside list with delimiter `,` in reverse order  :

```
//result
String joinedString = "C,B,A";
```

what is the best approach to achieve this? 
currently I use index loop :

```
String joinedString = "";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     String string = list.get(i);
     joinedString = joinedString + string + ",";
}
//to remove ',' from the last string
if(joinedString.length() > 0) {
    joinedString = joinedString.substring(0, joinedString.length() - 1);
}

//Output    
C,B,A
```

Comment: If it works, it's generally good enough.

Comment: is it? but could I achieve it better without using index loop?

Comment: You might find [How to get a reversed list view on a list in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962766/how-to-get-a-reversed-list-view-on-a-list-in-java) useful if you don't want to modify the original list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the list by calling [`Collections.reverse(List<?> list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse-java.util.List-) on it, iterate the list in reverse.

If you don't know the list type, use a [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) to iterate the list backwards without loss of performance, e.g. an normal `i = 0; i < size()` loop over a `LinkedList` would otherwise perform badly.

To join the values separated by commas, use a [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) (Java 8+).

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");

StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
for (ListIterator<String> iter = list.listIterator(list.size()); iter.hasPrevious(); )
    joiner.add(iter.previous());
String result = joiner.toString();

System.out.println(result); // print: C,B,A
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java/40375897

Comment: the same IDEA using streams: `String result= Stream.iterate(list.listIterator(list.size()), it -> it)
                        /*.takeWhile(ListIterator::hasPrevious) // java 9+ */
                        .limit(list.size()) /*java 8 workaround*/
                        .map(ListIterator::previous)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));`

Comment: @AndreyLavrukhin That is extremely bad stream logic, because you're violating the contract of [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) when you call [`previous()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous--), because it is not a *stateless* function. To do it correctly, see [**How to convert an iterator to a stream?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24511052/5221149)

Answer (score 3):

The simplest is to use [`Collections#reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) and [`String#join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-).

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
Collections.reverse(list);
String joinedString = String.join(",", list);
```

Comment: Good thing OP used `Arrays.asList(...)` and not `List.of(...)`, since this solution wouldn't work otherwise.

Comment: Can't find `List.of` by Googling. Got a link to documentation? @Andreas

Comment: Added in Java 9: [`List.of(E...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)) --- Or this link to see [all the overloads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#i15).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution using Java 8:

```
Collections.reverse(list);

//res contains the desired string
String res = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a Supplier

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
int i[] = { list.size() };
Supplier<String> supplier = () -> (i[0] > 0) ? list.get(--i[0]) : null;
String s, reverse = "";
while ((s = supplier.get()) != null) {
        reverse +=","+s;
}
reverse = (reverse.length() > 0) ? reverse = reverse.substring(1): "" ;
```

or insted of while loop

```
reverse = list.stream().map(l->supplier.get()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be usefull joining-like collector:

```
    public static Collector<CharSequence, ?, String> joiningReversed(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence prefix, CharSequence suffix) {
    return Collector.of(StringBuilder::new,
            (sb, item) -> {
                if (sb.length() != 0) {
                    sb.insert(0, delimiter);
                }
                sb.insert(0, item);
            },
            (a, b) -> {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            },
            sb -> sb.insert(0, prefix).append(suffix).toString());
    }
```

and use it in streams:

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    String result = list.stream()
                .collect(joiningReversed(",", "", ""));
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Note: it works for any sequential stream, even undetermined length.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using Comparator.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
list.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
String joinedString = String.join(",", list);
```

Comment: OP doesn't not want value *sorted*, just reverse of current order. The fact that the example shown has values in ascending order is arbitrary.

Comment: this is an overkill. it is sufficient to reverse it

Answer (score 0):

One method use `StringBuilder`

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("A", "b", "c","d");
    for (int i = 0; i < strs.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(strs.get(i));
        if (i != strs.size() - 1) {
            sb.append(",");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.reverse().toString());
```