# Reversing list throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, reverse, indexoutofboundsexception

The method is supposed to revers the order of items in the List

```
public class ZrcalnaSlikaSeznama {
    public static <T> List<T> zrcalnaSlika(List<T> seznam) {
        int length = seznam.size();
        List<T> seznam2 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (T x : seznam){
            seznam2.add(length-1, x);
            length--;
        }
        return seznam2;
    }
}
```

But it throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Why? And how to fix the method?

Comment: What is the value of `length-1` when the ArrayList is empty?

Comment: Change your strategy: iterate on the original list backwards, and add to the new list. To know why you get the exception, read the javadoc of add().

Comment: Use Collections.reverse() to reverse the list

Comment: This is what you're looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962766/how-to-get-a-reversed-list-view-on-a-list-in-java

Comment: Downvoted because you did not provide any information about your actual issue. Your code is missing the error information, the stacktrace, an explanation and the example input that actually leads to the crash. Please read [ask] and [mcve], thanks.

Comment: The naming of your `length` variable is bad. It starts at length but you decrement it, suggesting that the list shrinks, but its not. Actually, your `length` is not the length but an `index` of the next item you want to touch. Consider renaming it.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

The main issue of your code is that you assumed you could directly add something to a later position in an `ArrayList`, using `add(index, element)`.

But it is not an array, it is a list. This is not possible. The `add` method does not allow adding **beyond its current size**, which is still `0`. As explained in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,E)) of this method:

> Throws: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the index is out of range `(index < 0 || index > size())`

---

### Fix

To fix your code, and still going this approach, you would first have to ensure that the list already has the desired size by prefilling it with garbage data, like lots of `null`s. And then doing what you tried to do, but by using `set`, not `add` (otherwise you would not change existing entries but shift them around). So something like this:

```
List<T> reversed = new ArrayList<>();

// Fill with garbage
for (int i = 0; i < seznam.size(); i++) {
    reversed.add(null);
}

// Exchange against elements
int i = seznam.size() - 1;
for (T element : seznam) {
    reversed.set(i, element);
    i--;
}
```

---

### Proper solution

Obviously, filling the list first with garbage data is not an ideal approach. You can do much better. How about adding to your new list forwards, but iterating the original items backwards. So if you have `[1, 2, 3]` you add, `3`, `2` and finally `1`. This can be accomplished easily:

```
List<T> reversed = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = seznam.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversed.add(seznam.get(i));
}
```

---

### Note

There are also other approaches to this and Java also has already built-in methods for this, if that is an option for you, i.e. `Collections.reverse(list)`.

For example, see [How to get a reversed list view on a list in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962766/how-to-get-a-reversed-list-view-on-a-list-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to reverse the order of your items in the List using the for-loop() could be :

```
public class ZrcalnaSlikaSeznama {

    public static <T> List<T> zrcalnaSlika(List<T> seznam) {
        int length = seznam.size();
        List<T> seznam2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = length-1; i>=0; i--){
            seznam2.add(seznam.get(i));
        }

        return seznam2;
    }

}
```

Comment: While this works, it does not explain why OPs code failed. Which is likely the reason why OP asked in the first place.